# Java/LibGDX - Sound files have a ~2 second delay?

Tags: java, libgdx

Currently developing a small game in LibGDX, and my sound files play, but only after a significant delay.

The main issue is a sound that is played upon pressing a key. I have it firing as soon as the key is pressed, and for obvious reasons, I cannot have the sound play 2 seconds after the user presses the key.

I've tried changing file types, file sizes, shortening the audio, and have currently landed on a 23kb .ogg file that is less than 1 second long.

I've also tried running it without anything in my render method, as I read online that poor rendering was the case for some people, to no avail.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: This usually isn't such a problem, so it's likely due to something in the coding or configuration. Can you show the code used to play your sounds? A common latency issue arises when sound assets are not preloaded and held in memory, but are loaded and decompressed from file with each play call. (Happens more times than you might expect.) There may also be other aspects that perhaps could be prepared in advance but are not.

Comment: Yes. And if your file is `ogg` and you’re not preloading, then it has to load *and* decompress it before playing it.

Comment: where is your code?